# Function to calculate product of numbers using 'x' operator?

Tags: .net, string, parsing, infix-operator

What function will input a string which could either contain numbers or the multiplication of two numbers using the `'x'` character as an operator?

For example:

- If the input is `"6 x 11"` then the output should be `66`.
- If the input is `"78`" then the output should be `78`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use several System.String methods to accomplish this. What have you tried?

One option:

```
public int GetValue(string input)
{
    int output = 0;

    if (input.Contains("x"))
    {
        string[] a = input.Split('x');
        int x = int.Parse(a[0]);
        int y = int.Parse(a[1]);

        output = x * y;
    }
    else
    {
        output = int.Parse(input);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Of course, this ignores any input validation.

Comment: How about case-insensitive?

Comment: @CJ7 You could change the string to upper or lowercase via the .ToUpper or .ToLower methods.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
        public int GetProduct(string input)
        {
            int result = 1;
            input = input.ToUpper();

            if (input.Contains("X"))
            {
                string[] array = input.Split('x');
                for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (IsNumber(array[index]))
                    {
                        result = result * Convert.ToInt32(array[index]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            }
            return result;
        }

        bool IsNumber(string text)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$");
            return regex.IsMatch(text);
        }
```